# Problema com POST no Javascript + Ajax

Tags: javascript, github

Galera estou fazendo um teste, e preciso desenvolver uma tela de cadastro usando a API do GitHub https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create ...
Segue o código:

```
//Add repositories on GitHub
$('#add-repository').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token mytoken");
    },
    data: '{"name": "test","description":"repos test","homepage": "https://test.com","auto_init":true}'
  }).done(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

da seguinte forma ele funciona.. porem eu quero receber os dados do POST e passar no data..

```
//Add repositories on GitHub
$('#add-repository').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token mytoken");
    },
    data: form
  }).done(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

Tentei assim porem ele retorna erro 400(Bad Request)..

```
//Add repositories on GitHub
$('#add-repository').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var description = $("#description").val();
  var homepage = $("#homepage").val();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token mytoken");
    },
    data: '{"name": '+name+',"description": '+description+',"homepage": '+homepage+',"auto_init":true}'
  }).done(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

Assim retorna o mesmo erro, só o primeiro exemplo cadastra o repositorio, porem preciso receber os dados passados no formulário AGRADEÇO!

Answer (score 0):

Problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
//Add repositories on GitHub
$('#add-repository').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var name = $("#name").val();
var description = $("#description").val();
var homepage = $("#homepage").val();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token mytoken");
    },
    data: '{"name": "'+name+'",' +
    '"description":"'+description+'",' +
    '"homepage": "'+homepage+'",' +
    '"auto_init":true}'
  }).done(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```